# how to add the following feature to a tfidf matrix?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

Hello I have a list called list_cluster, that looks as follows:

```
list_cluster=["hello,this","this is a test","the car is red",...]
```

I am using TfidfVectorizer to produce a model as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
with open('vectorizerTFIDF.pickle', 'rb') as infile:
    tdf = pickle.load(infile)
tfidf2 = tdf.transform(list_cluster)
```

then I would like to add new features to this matrix called tfidf2, I have a list as follows:

```
dates=['010000000000', '001000000000', '001000000000', '000000000001', '001000000000', '000000000010',...]
```

this list has the same lenght of list_cluster, and represents the date has 12 positions and in the place where is the 1 is the corresponding month of the year,

for instance '010000000000' represents february,

in order to use it as feature first I tried:

```
import numpy as np
dates=np.array(listMonth)
dates=np.transpose(dates)
```

to get a numpy array and then to transpose it in order to concatenate it with the first matrix tfidf2

```
print("shape tfidf2: "+str(tfidf2.shape),"shape dates: "+str(dates.shape))
```

in order to concatenate my vector and matrix I tried:

```
tfidf2=np.hstack((tfidf2,dates[:,None]))
```

However this is the output:

```
shape tfidf2: (11159, 1927) shape dates: (11159,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 230, in <module>
    tfidf2=np.hstack((tfidf2,dates[:,None]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 278, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

the shape seems good, but I am not sure what is failing, I would like to appreciate support to concatenate this feature to my tfidf2 matrix, thanks in advance for the atention,

Comment: what are the `dtypes`?  If `dates` is 1d, then `transpose` does nothing.  But the `[:,None]` should give it the proper 2d shape.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for the support, yes dates is 1d, how to convert it to a matrix of 1,11159 to then concatenate with my matrix?

Comment: `(11159,1)` is the right shape for `hstack` (concatenate with axis=1).  That's why I'm asking about `dtypes` to see if there's something else about the arrays that's problem (despite what the error says).

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for the help, ok I think that there is a dtypes problem since dates is an array composed by strings, I need to find a way to turn it into an array of numbers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert all strings to numerics for sklearn. One way to do this is use the LabelBinarizer class in the preprocessing module of sklearn. This creates a new binary column for each unique value in your original column.

If dates is the same number of rows as `tfidf2` then I think this will work.

```
# create tfidf2
tfidf2 = tdf.transform(list_cluster)

#create dates
dates=['010000000000', '001000000000', '001000000000', '000000000001', '001000000000', '000000000010',...]

# binarize dates
lb = LabelBinarizer()
b_dates = lb.fit_transform(dates)

new_tfidf = np.concatenate((tfidf2, b_dates), axis=1)
```